# cloudfiles remote file problem

Tags: php, cloudfiles

I am trying to load a file to my Cloud Files Container from a remote file.

Below is the example code a Cloud Files Support person gave me:

```
<?php

    require('cloud/cloudfiles.php');

    $res  = fopen("http://images.piccsy.com/cache/images/66653-d71e1b-320-469.jpg", "rb");
    $temp = tmpfile();
    $size = 0.0;
    while (!feof($res))
    {
        $bytes = fread($res, 1024);
        fwrite($temp, $bytes);
        $size += (float) strlen($bytes);
    }

    fclose($res);
    fseek($temp, 0);

    //
    $auth = new CF_Authentication('user','token ');
    //Calling the Authenticate method returns a valid storage token and allows you to connect to the CloudFiles Platform.
    $auth->authenticate();

    $conn = new CF_Connection($auth);

    $container = $conn->create_container("example");
    $object = $container->create_object("example.jpg");
    $object->content_type = "image/jpeg";
    $object->write($temp, $size);

    fclose($temp);
?>
```

The problem I am getting is the below error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function create_container() on a non-object in /home2/sharingi/public_html/daily_dose/remote_test.php on line 24
```

Not sure exactly what I am not noticing here.

Answer (score 0):

It seems `$conn` did not successfully instantiate an object. That is the problem, but the solution is not clear cut.

Is `CF_Connection` defined? Does `error_reporting(E_ALL)` give you more helpful info? What does `var_dump($conn instanceof CF_Connection)` output?

This should point you in the right direction.

Comment: Should be in the `cloudfiles.php` and seems `CF_Auth` would error before if not?

Comment: `var_dump` returns `Notice: Undefined variable: conn in /home2/sharingi/public_html/daily_dose/remote_test.php on line 5
bool(false)` and `error_reporting` returns
`Notice: Undefined offset: 8 in /home2/sharingi/public_html/daily_dose/cloud/cloudfiles.php on line 1588`

Comment: Scratch that. If I put `var_dump` after the call to `$conn` it returns `bool(true)`